# How can I add a thematic break like a line through with padding on a Text Widget?

Tags: flutter

I'm not sure how to describe it, but what I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Here's what I tried so far:

```
Text(
  "text",
  style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far. You can use the [Row](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) widget to get started.

Comment: You're right, @KirollosMorkos. Sorry for that, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(child: Container(height: 1.0, color: Colors.black, margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),)),
        Text('Hello world'),
        Expanded(child: Container(height: 1.0, color: Colors.black, margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),)),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: You're awesome! I'm new to Flutter and I had no idea how I'd accomplish this. Thank you so much!